# Do I need the same capacity connector on neutral side as on the live side?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, connector, power-electronics, mains

This is basic question but I will ask anyways. Our real case scenario is similar to the drawing below.

[image]

Lets assume 100A is flowing into the circuit that means 100A enters the circuit, gets divided at each resister (parallel circuit) and then combines again at the neutral side to make 100A.

My question is do I need the same 100A capacity connector on the neutral side that I used on the live side? I am a little confused because at Live side voltage=120, but on neutral side V=0. I know there will be I^2R losses though.

Comment: But the current is still 100A as you said, so why could you use lower current rated?

Comment: Current capacity always flows in loops. Even lightning current flows in a loop.

Comment: Because V=0 at neutral side?

Comment: Current handling capacity has nothing to do with voltage. You've already answered your own question.

Comment: as mentioned below, 3 hours ago, but in BIG SHOUTING LETTERS up here: You should also not be playing around with Mains voltage and 100A if you have to ask this kind of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said yourself that the same current flows back along the neutral as goes out the line side.  It should be obvious therefore that both sides need the same current handling capability.

The voltage each wire is at relative to some point (like ground), is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same voltage and current capacity for the neutral connector as the live side. I say "voltage" because, in many wiring systems, neutral and live can become swapped so, what you do for live you should also do for neutral with respect to current AND voltage. Connectors DO HAVE voltage ratings too.

Comment: However in my case, it will not be swapping. So would that change your answer?

Comment: You not swapping is immaterial - sometimes "the infrastructure" can swap live and neutral without you knowing. You have to be aware of this. I'm not saying it happens often or on all infrastructures but you are not in control of this normally.

Comment: And as far as the current is concerned, swapping is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: A single fault (open circuit neutral) results in the neutral conductor being live at mains voltage. As such, the neutral is considered a 'live part' and must be appropriately insulated.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere nicely put.

Comment: You should also not be playing around with Mains voltage and 100A if you have to ask this kind of question

Comment: @Christian I think you need to put that comment below the question and not my answer.